# StoreContext.GetAppLicenseAsync is returning addons for unlicensed users (Desktop Bridge)

Tags: windows-store, desktop-bridge

I am testing a desktop bridge app using 2 test users (User1 and User2).

It has one durable add-on and User1 has a redeemable promotional code to use for the add-on. User2 does not.

User1 has redeemed the code on one PC and that works okay, giving it access to the add-on. However, User2 can also use the add-on on the same machine even though it has not redeemed any codes. In this case, GetAppLicenseAsync() is returning the add-on license regardless of which user is signed in.

I then added User1 as a new user on an existing PC but when I run the app, it can not use the add-on because GetAppLicenseAsync() does not return any add-on licenses regardless of which user is signed in.

Based on the documentation, my expectation was that User1 would be able to use the add-on from up to ten devices (as stated on the Windows store purchase screen). I also expected that User2 would not be able to access the add-on from any devices.

Comment: I will follow your issue at MSDN, could you give me more details in that thread for me to analyze ?